# Automatically changes dictionary order/sort from HTTP response

Tags: angular, typescript

My API returns the following dictionary:

```
"positions": {
    "31": 18,
    "25": 12,
    "23": 12,
    "22": 12,
    "19": 12,
    "26": 9,
    "21": 9,
    "29": 9,
    "20": 9,
    "30": 9,
    "24": 6,
    "27": 6,
    "28": 6,
    "17": 3
}
```

When I receive this in Angular, it reorders the dictionary and sorts them by keys instead of by values. So I get something like this

```
"positions": {
    "17": 3, 
    "19": 12, 
    "20": 9, 
    ...
}
```

Why? Do I have to define a model for this KVP where I tell it that the keys are strings and not numbers? How would I do that?

I'd prefer not having to both sort my data on the backend and on the frontend.

Comment: Object keys are not guaranteed ordered. If you want some specific order, use an array or apply it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why?

The problem is [the way that the ECMAScript spec specifies this behavior](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) (which is really just a reflection of how runtimes have implemented this.

> 1. Let keys be a new empty List.
> 2. **For each own property key P of O that is an integer index, in ascending numeric index order**, do
>
>    1. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 3. For each own property key P of O that is a String but is not an integer index, in ascending chronological order of property creation, do
>
>    1. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 4. For each own property key P of O that is a Symbol, in ascending chronological order of property creation, do
>
>    1. Add P as the last element of keys.
> 5. Return keys.

So basically, integral keys will always come first in ascending (increasing) order.

Like jonrsharpe mentioned, you should probably make `positions` an array, either of key/value pair objects, or of other arrays that can act as tuples.